# Wordpress and https .htaccess

Tags: wordpress

here is `Wordpress` default code in `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What is correct way to provide only secure https connections? The code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Is it ok the 2nd and 3rd line to put after `Wordpress` code to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You should add that code before Wordpress, not after

```
# forcing SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!